# Unable to install all modules.See log /tmp/vmware/vmware-{Host}-vmware-14067.log for details.(Exit code1)

Tags: linux, vmware, parrot-os

While running VMware 16 pro in My Linux Kernel i got a Error Like this..[Here is the Error of Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnoHM.png)

Can Anyone give me solution for this :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The instructions told you to see the log file for details.  Did you?  Are you going to share the details?

Answer (score 8):

From:
[ubuntu 22.04 install vm workstation error](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Player/ubuntu-22-04-install-vm-workstation-error/td-p/2905277)

This is what helped me

```
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules
cd vmware-host-modules
git checkout workstation-16.2.3
make
tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
tar -cf vmmon.tar vmmon-only
mv vmnet.tar /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/
mv vmmon.tar /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Comment: worked instantly for me with a new kernel in almalinux 9 :)

Answer (score 7):

To use the VMware modules with newer kernels, you need some patches applied to the modules to be compatible.
There is a repository that keep track of the needed patches and published them
`https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules`

There is a branch which host the changes needed to compile with the workstation version 16 in newer kernels.

If you get that code and compile the patched version, your VMWare will work.

```
git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules
cd vmware-host-modules
git checkout workstation-16.2.3
sudo make ; sudo make install
```